# Retrieving the max datetime record in each group with multiple duplicate max datetime - MySQL Ask

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

There is a table with the name `'**work**'` that contains data as shown below:

```
Id  Name  a_Column  work_datetime
-----------------------------------------
1   A      A_1      1592110166
2   A      A_2      1592110166
3   A      A_3      1592110164
4   B      B_1      1582111665
5   B      B_2      1592110166
6   C      C_1      1592110166
```

If I run a query which group by `A` and `max(work_datetime)`, then there could be 2 selections for group with `Name='A'` but i need only one of them with `a_Column='A_1'` such that final desired output is as follows:-

```
Id   Name   a_Column   work_datetime
-----------------------------------------
1    A       A_1       1592110166
5    B       B_2       1592110166
6    C       C_1       1592110166
```

Handling duplicate records at the group by is something which mysql doesn't seem to support!

Any way i can achieve the required result?

Comment: How do you decide which value of `a_column` you want to display?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nick: So for eg i am using a_column based on the earliest Id in the table
Also i am using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

A simple option that works on all versions of MySQL is to filter with a subquery:

```
select w.*
from work w
where w.id = (
    select id 
    from work w1 
    where w1.name = w.name 
    order by work_datetime desc, a_column
    limit 1
)
```

For each `name`, this brings the row with the latest `work_datetime`; ties are broken by picking the row with the smallest `a_column` (which is how I understood your requirement).

For performance, you want an index on `(work_datetime, a_column, id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 8 you can use `row_number()` to assign a number to each row numbering the position of the row in the descending order of the time repeating for each name. Do that in a derived table and then just select the rows where this number is `1` from it.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.name,
       x.a_column,
       x.work_datetime
       FROM (SELECT w.id,
                    w.name,
                    w.a_column,
                    w.work_datetime,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY w.name
                                       ORDER BY w.work_datetime) rn
                    FROM work w) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

With `row_number()` there are no duplicates. Should there be two rows with the same name and time one of it is chosen randomly. If you want to retain the duplicates you can replace `row_number()` with `rank()`.